# Create polygons from connected components on a grid

Tags: opencv, geometry, polygon, shapely, connected-components

I have a grid of points like a single channel picture. I find the connected components using openCV with python. I want to get polygons of the connected components as shown below
Is there anyway to get something like shapely polygons from the grid and connected components labels? Also polygons can have holes in them.

[image]

Comment: Please add minimal sample input data and minimal reproducible code that explains exactly where you got stuck and people can start with!

Comment: The straight forward approach would be to create a square polygon for each point, create a union of those polygons and finally smoothen corners. If you need more help, please add some code to start from.